# How to resolve Delphi error: Incompatible types: 'PWideChar' and 'Pointer'

Tags: delphi, pointers, delphi-xe4

I have this piece of code from Delphi 7:

```
var
  lpRgnData: PRgnData;
  PC: PChar;  
  PR: PRect;
  ...

  PC := @(lpRgnData^.Buffer[0]);
```

In Delphi XE4 it gives the following compile error:

```
Incompatible types: 'PWideChar' and 'Pointer'
```

How should this code be updated to work correctly in XE4?

Thanks

Comment: Looks as if you need to change `PChar` to `PAnsiChar`. Could be wrong though.

Comment: The buffer is an array of byte. So change PChar to PByte.

Comment: @JerryDodge using (pre-unicode) `PChar` for things that should have used `PByte` is what got a lot of legacy code (like this) into trouble in the first place.  If you need bytes, better to use `PByte`, imo.

Comment: @J..., pre-Unicode PChar was an intrinsic type, but PByte was not. So most implementations used PChar for a byte pointer since the TP days. See [Taking a big PByte of pointer math](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/abauer/2008/01/24/38852).

Comment: @JerryDodge: The first thing I tried was to change PChar to PAnsiChar but this just changed the error message to "Incompatible types: 'PAnsiChar' and 'Pointer'". Changing it to PByte is what worked.

Comment: Yeah, I skimmed over the Q too quickly without observing what `PRgnData` actually was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether or not this compiles depends upon the setting of the [type-checked pointers option](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Type-checked_pointers_(Delphi)). You clearly have enabled that option which is an excellent decision. Doing so results in stricter type checking.

With type-checked pointers disabled, your code does compile. With type-checked pointers enabled, your code does not compile, which is what you want because your code is not valid.

Now, on to the types in question. They are defined in the `Windows` unit like this:

```
type
  PRgnData = ^TRgnData;
  {$EXTERNALSYM _RGNDATA}
  _RGNDATA = record
    rdh: TRgnDataHeader;
    Buffer: array[0..0] of Byte;
    Reserved: array[0..2] of Byte;
  end;
  TRgnData = _RGNDATA;
  {$EXTERNALSYM RGNDATA}
  RGNDATA = _RGNDATA;
```

The benefit of using type-checked pointers is that the compiler can tell you that what you are doing is not valid. It knows that `lpRgnData^.Buffer[0]` has type `Byte` and so `@(lpRgnData^.Buffer[0])` has type `^Byte`. And it knows that is not compatible with `PChar` which is an alias for `PWideChar`, that is `^WideChar`.

Fix your code by changing the type of `PC` to `^Byte` or `PByte`.